# Absolute Value Theorem for Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-value

Given an alternating sequence.

The Absolute Value Theorem states that: 
If the limit of the  absolute value of the sequence is 0 then the limit of the original sequence is also 0.

However if, the limit of the absolute value of the sequence is not 0 (some value) then there is "no conclusion".

But wouldn't that just imply that the sequence would alternate between this value making the limit DNE and therefore the sequence divergent? Or is this only for all cases where the sequence is in fact alternating.

Comment: Hint: Consider the following sequences: $$a_n=(-1)^n,\qquad b_n=1$$What are $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|b_n|$?  Do $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge and diverge together?  What can you draw from this example?

Comment: I guess it would be divergent for alternating sequence cases only then

Comment: But can you show that it ***must*** alternate only given that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=1$?  Can you show anything given only this much information?

Comment: no you would have to know what Xn is?

Comment: So I think you've answered your own question ;)

Comment: (By the way, you can try writing an answer to your very own question!  I'm looking forward to it $\ddot\smile$ )

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Suppose ther are infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n=1$ and infinitely many $m$ such that $a_m=-1.$ Then $(|a_k|)_k$ converges to $1$ but $(a_k)_k$ does not converge . For example let $a_n=1$ when $n$ is prime, and $a_m=-1$ when $m$ is not prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting limit from using the Absolute Value Theorem must be 0 to show convergence of the original sequence.

The resulting limit can also be a non zero number which, in general means that there is no conclusion.

However, when the resulting limit is a non zero number and the original sequence is an alternating sequence, you can conclude that the sequence will alternate between this non zero number. Making the limit of the original sequence DNE which implies that the sequence is divergent.

Comment: Rather, if there exists some $N>0$ such that $\operatorname{sgn}(x_n)=\operatorname{sgn}(x_N)$ for all $n>N$, then the sequence is convergent, else, it is divergent.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This is exactly what i wrote.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima :P And I've already upvoted you in sight of that.  I mostly wanted to point out that alternating usually implies $(-1)^n$, but such simple sign changes are not what is needed, but rather that the sign changes *eventually*, or never.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I simply thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|x_n |=L>0$$

if, for enough great values of $n $, $x_n$ keeps a constant sign then the sequence $(x_n) $ will converge to $L $ or $-L $.

if its sign changes, it will diverge.

Answer (score 0):

The continuity of $x \mapsto |x|$ implies that the convergence of $\langle a_j \rangle$ implies the convergence of $\langle |a_j| \rangle$, so taking the contrapositive gives the divergence of $\langle a_j \rangle$.